# What does 250V DC + AC peak mean?

Tags: oscilloscope, ratings

My oscilloscope's inputs are rated "250V DC + AC peak (10 KHz)." Does this mean it would withstand mains voltage (325V peak) or only 250V DC? I have **no** plans on doing this any time soon, I am only curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you add peak voltage to your dc offset, it must be less than 250V.

this was verified with dc and a 10kHz ac wave.

Comment: So practically, it means it can only take in AC with a peak voltage of 250V?

Comment: yes, but i would stay well below that threshold, i hate buying fuses.

Comment: I think more than the fuse would blow, it would probably damage the inputs or at least reduce their performance.

Comment: in my experience a fuse blows, but play it safe.

Comment: Hmm I haven't seen any fuses on the mainboard of my scope, but they could be hidden under the RF shielding.

Comment: i use relatively expensive scopes, they probably do not include this on cheaper scopes. all about cost.

Comment: My scope retailed for $3,300 USD new, but I only bought it for £150 (approx. $200.)

Comment: The one I have been using was bought at academic discount for $3,300 used. I believe it is significantly more new. No idea how much the others cost, but they have a fuse they blow if you do this to them.

Answer (score 1):

AC signals sometimes ride on a DC voltage level. On the scope you may see a sin wave of +60 to - 40 VDC. This is 100 V Ac signal riding on a 10 V DC voltage.

I once worked with a 10 V peak to peak sin and cos signal from a resolver. The reference signal had a 0 V, 400 mV or 800 mV DC level applied to it. A multiplexer would switch between 3 different resolvers based on DC level.

Your scope could handle anything from 250 V peak AC signal to a peak 125 VAC on top of 125 V DC to a pure 250 V DC or any mix as long as the AC Peak signal + the DC level is less then 250 V

For dealing with High voltage signals, use high voltage probes. These typically reduce the signal by a factor of 10 or more. So a 250 VAC signal become a 25 V signal.